# Как прописать субдомены в hosts файле, ос Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7, hosts

День добрый!В общем тема такая на веб-сервере установлены Алисы *.domain.local -> domain.local

Задача теперь такаяПри изменении файла hosts на:127.0.0.1 domain.local127.0.0.1 1.domain.local

Срабатывают домены "domain.local" и "1.domain.local" а необходимо сделать все доступные имена что-бы обращались к домену. Вариант: 127.0.0.1 *.domain.local - пробовал, не помогает. Возможно ли как-нибудь решить мою проблему? что-бы не дописывать over(9000) строчек в hosts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wildcard  в windows никогда не работал.

Comment: Возможно вы знаете какую-нибудь стороннюю программу?

Comment: Задача в целом какая?

Comment: Задача в целом: "есть сайт в моем случае domain.local человек регестрирует себе скажем персональный 'сайт' и доступ к нему с помощью *.domain.local. если * не пустое то переадресовывать на нормулью внутреннюю страницу." Почти вся задача перефразирована - т.к договор о конфедициальности подписан. Я покапал в сторону Wildcard Windows. И понял что мне легче до работы и до любимой Ubuntu добраться завтра =)

Comment: Ну дык освоили бы днс, поднять то там делов на 5 мин, одна зона, зато какой профит.

Comment: Все-таки сделать это на моей Ubuntu мне кажется проще и быстрее. Все равно до работы осталось 8 часов. Спасибо за подсказку про "Wildcard"

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте Попробуйте так
*domain.local

Comment: Не помогает.